# How to convert column of ArrayType to Dictionary in Pyspark

Tags: sql, dictionary, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am doing collect_list on a dataframe that yields me the required `column(TASourceId)` as below:

```
[{"TASourceId": "Source1", "flag": "true"}, {"TASourceId": "Source2", "flag": "true"}]
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT col1, col2,col3, collect_list(struct(TASourceId, flag)) as TASourceId
FROM table
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Is it possible to get a dictionary of dictionary objects as the output of the column, like the following?

```
{"col1":{"TASourceId": "Source1", "flag": "true"}, "col2":{"TASourceId": "Source2", "flag": "true"}}
```

I am trying to use `spark UDF` to get this, but getting the following error:

> Expected zero arguments for class dict error.

Comment: Please add sample input and example with the code you have tried. Best would be src rows in tabular format.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a sample as your array and converted it to a dictionary.

```
a=[{"TASourceId": "Source1", "flag": "true"}, {"TASourceId": "Source2", "flag": "true"}]
s={}
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    s["col"+str(i)]=a[i]
print(s)
```